# Calculate random value * unknown value = 1

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm having trouble importing the models from maya fbx to unity at the right scale. I detected the problem being inside Unity when importing the fbx file.

There's not really a workaround this other than changing by hand the .meta file:

```
useFileScale: 0
```

Since modelImporter.isFileScaleUsed in Unity is read-only, I can't change the value with a script, but I can change the global scale:

```
globalScale
```

Say I have file scale at 0.01, the normal value is 1 for scale, how can I calculate 0.01 * 100 = 1 with UnityScript, meaning I need to get the value 100 out of equation `0.01 * ? = 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide 1 by the value you know. For example, if `a * b = 1` then `1/a = b`.

Comment: Crap that was easy, don't know what I thought that dividing 1 by the know value would give me a decimal result. Thank you

Comment: it might give a decimal answer-  depending on the value of `a`

Comment: a is always 1 in the context above that's the scale exported out maya( 3d application )